# ID3D10Device::RSSetState to be called every frame?

Tags: c++, directx

I am trying to create a ID3D10RasterizerState with direct3D10, and then call

ID3D10Device::RSSetState()
with the proper information. However, whenever the window get rescaled, or when the app goes fullscreen, the rasterizerstate seems to reset to the default state. I have tried to set the state with WM_SIZE messages, but awkwardly, nothing seems to happen...

It works properly when I call RSSetState() every frame, but that seems highly inefficient.

Does anyone know a solution to this? It seems to be poorly documented on msdn.

**Code:**

```
bool TestGameApp::InitGame()
{
    D3D10_RASTERIZER_DESC desc;
    desc.AntialiasedLineEnable = TRUE;
    desc.CullMode = D3D10_CULL_NONE;
    desc.DepthBias = 0;
    desc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
    desc.FillMode = D3D10_FILL_SOLID;
    desc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
    desc.MultisampleEnable = true;
    desc.ScissorEnable = FALSE;
    desc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;

    m_pD3DDevice->CreateRasterizerState(&desc,m_pRSState);
    m_pD3DDevice->RSSetState(m_pRSState);

    //...more code
}
```

***WndProc:***

```
switch( message )
{
    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        m_pD3DDevice->RSSetState(m_pRSState);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Go ahead and call it every frame.  It's not inefficient; that's the way you're supposed to do it.  Game engines often call it (and other SetState methods) *many* times per frame in order to switch render states for different parts of the frame.

Comment: Since I don't need to change it every frame, it seems inefficient to me. If you need to change it every frame, I agree, but this is not the case. Is there no way around?

Comment: @xcrypt, it's such an insignificant cost it's seriously not worth worrying about!

Comment: It's more of an attitude :) Maybe the benefits are really small and not noticeable, but I still try to avoid writing abundant code. Your reply is great side-information, but unfortunately it's not an  answer to my question.

Comment: @xcrypt: I think that Nathan DID give you the solution- it's designed to be called every frame. You WILL find lots of places to optimize, but you're wasting your time here. (If it's an attitude it's a poor one. :P http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/the-real-cost-of-performance.html )

Comment: @KTF your opinion is invalid. But more importantly, The question is not about design principles or standards. It's a pure technical question. I do not need lectures about why minimal performance gains may or may not be a good thing. This is how I like to code. And yes, I am aware of all the quotes / lectures in the world telling me not to do it, I know why people consider it a bad thing in an 'economically efficient environment'. That does not mean it's not a great exercise.

Comment: lol @ your opinion that my opinion is invalid. I am rather curious, did you ever find your answer? I was under the impression that the answer is that it is meant to be called every frame. (as the response is marked as the answer)

Comment: @KTF Not really :( I will one day perhaps look into it, but then again there's not much I can change about how DirectX works...